# ANT: several filesets for the javac task

Tags: ant, build.xml, fileset

I have a ANT build file with two different filesets:

```
<fileset id="fs1">  <include name="source1\**" />  </fileset>
<fileset id="fs2">  <include name="source2\**" />  </fileset>
```

and want to use both of them in the same javac task.

Of course, I could write

```
<javac ...>
     <include name="source1\**" />
     <include name="source2\**" />
</javac>
```

but I want the selection of the files occurs outside, because my javac-task will be called several times with different parameters.

A solution would be to copy all the files in a temp directory and call javac on it. But you will admit it is not very satisfying...

More over: is there a solution to concatenate two filesets in a single one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution, using `patternset.`

```
<patternset id="ps1">  <include name="source1\**" />  </patternset>
<patternset id="ps2">  <include name="source2\**" />  </patternset>

<javac ...>
  <patternset>
    <patternset refid="ps1" />
    <patternset refid="ps2" />
  </patternset>
</javac>
```